# Why did the Aharonov-Bohm effect mystify people?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, topology

Of course it is intriguing. But I think the Schroedinger equation for a charged particle in a magnetic field was known at the very beginning of wave mechanics. Therefore, the [A-B effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect) should not be more exotic than the Schroedinger equation.

A-B effect is simply an immediate consequence of the Schroedinger equation. So why was it debatable?

Comment: In the [Aharonov–Bohm effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect), the magnetic field is zero along the electrons path. So, in this case, the Schrodinger equation is the free particle equation. The Aharonov–Bohm effect is a topological effect where the role of the potentials $A_\mu$ (vs electric/magnetic fields) in the creation of a phase difference for two different paths of electrons, is crucial.

Comment: No, in the schrodinger equation, you have $A_\mu$ which you know is nonzero.

Comment: If you take a constant magnetic field, you may choose the Coulomb gauge, and you may express $\vec A$ as a function of $\vec B$, $\vec A = -\frac{1}{2} \vec r \wedge \vec B$, so finally there is only the magnetic field in the Schrodinger equation, see for instance the formula $(13)$ page $7$ of this [paper](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph216/QMemfield_12.pdf)

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99505/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.