# Aharonov Bohm effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, potential

Not much about the underlying math, but how can an electromagnetic field exist when the electric and magnetic field is zero?

Comment: The potential can exist. It's like asking how gravitational potential energy can exist on a flat surface. It exists, it just doesn't do anything because there is no derivatives, meaning no force. The special thing here is that apparently this is not always the case.

Comment: The answers in the linked duplicates are highly debatable.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56926/2451 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99505/2451

Comment: If the previous answers are wrong, then e.g. use a bounty for better answers rather than asking the same question again in a new thread.

Comment: Ya I have voted to reopen the question.